# upgrade ocsigen error

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

I want to upgrade the ocsigen to 2.1 in my freebsd box.

```
$pkg_info | grep -i ocsigen
ocsigen-1.1.0_1     Web programming framework for OCaml

$cat /usr/ports/www/ocsigen/Makefile | grep -i version
POPORTVERSION=    2.1

$sudo pormaster ocsigen
...
===>  Building for ocaml-tyxml-2.1
gmagmake: *** no rule to create “files/META.in” needed by “files/META”。 Stop
StoStop in /usr/ports/textproc/ocaml-tyxml.
...
===>>> You can restart from the point of failure with this command line
porportmaster <flags> www/ocsigen textproc/ocaml-tyxml
```

Maybe it is a simple error, but i cannot fix it by myself.

Sincerely!

Answer (score 2):

You should now use OPAM, the "standard" tool for managing source distributions of OCaml packages. OPAM is available here:

http://opam.ocamlpro.com/

Comment: You need to use GNU make when building opam.  There was a [bug report](https://github.com/hcarty/ocamlbrew/issues/17) against [ocamlbrew](https://github.com/hcarty/ocamlbrew) about this which has some more information.